# Cannot select a DOM element in Google Chrome Console without inspecting the element first using Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I run into something really strange with Google Chrome Dev Console.

Firstly I reload my page (`ctrl` + `F5`), then I launch Google Chrome Dev console (`F12`) and try to type in

```
document.getElementById('myElement')
```

to which Chrome's console responds with:

```
null
```

It's weird because I can actually see my element on the page and after I inspected the element using Chrome Dev Tools (right click on the element and choose `Inspect`) and switched back into the Console tab and typed again: `document.getElementById('myElement')` I finally got a correct result:

```
<input type="text" id="myElement" class="urEdf2Txt" autocomplete="off" size="10" maxlength="6" value="1.39" />
```

Note: I always waited until the page is fully loaded and waited until the element is fully visible before trying the procedure described above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this normally happens on `iframe`. try to see if the target element is in an `iframe` in the page.